# Question regarding the projection of a vector onto the nullspace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, projection, pseudoinverse

So for a matrix $A$, we have that it's nullspace is spanned by the columns of $(1-A^+A)$ where $A^+$ is the pseudo inverse of $A$. I am pretty sure the projection of a vector $v$ onto the nullspace of $A$ is then given by

$$Proj(v)=(1-A^+A)v$$

since the remaining component of $v$ is given by $[v-Proj(v)]=A^+Av$ which is perpendicular to the column space of $(1-A^+A)$ which means it is perpendicular to the nullspace of $A$.

If this is true, then the $Proj(v)$ given should have the minimum norm error with $v$ when considering all possible vectors in the nullspace of $A$. But, we can also find the nullspace vector with minimum norm error using the properties of the pseudo inverse, with

$$\min_{x\in Null(A)}|| x-v||^2=\min_{c}||(1-A^+A)c-v||^2$$

Which using the least squares property of the pseudo inverse gives the minimizing norm error nullspace vector as

$$x=(1-A^+A)(1-A^+A)^+v$$

This is different from $Proj(v)$ given before, so I was wondering is the first $Proj(v)$ incorrect?

Comment: Ok, I think they are the same from some roundabout reasoning. I was mainly wondering because of some seemingly disagreeable numerical examples in matlab, but turning down the numerical tolerance on the pseudo inverse calculation seems to show that the two above projections are equivalent for different random matrices.